# Python: ID error when importing csv file with pandas

Tags: python, windows, pandas, csv, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to Import a csv file saved in a local Folder. When I use Anaconda Python Notebook I have no Problems, while using Zeppelin I do have issues.
The code I am using, that works fine in Anaconda, is:

```
#import csv data

frequency=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\L18938\\Desktop\\Vehicle_to_grid\\analysis\\Frequency_March_2018.csv", nrows=86401)
```

However, when running it on Zeppelin, I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4025)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:8031)
IOError: File C:\Users\L18938\Desktop\Vehicle_to_grid\analysis\Frequency_March_2018.csv does not exist
```

Obviously, the file exists and there are no Errors in the path spelling.

[image]

I have tryied / or double \, but nothing changes. Also

```
os.chdir("C:/Users/L18938/Desktop/Vehicle_to_grid/analysis")
```

or

```
os.listdir("C:/Users/L18938/Desktop/Vehicle_to_grid/analysis")
```

Any idea? thank you in advance

Comment: It's strange, It won't happen....

Comment: I think `Frequency_March_2018.csv` does not exist) check the path again

Comment: Is it possible could be related to os.path or os.chdir? To be honest I didn't set any, but maybe they are set by default

Comment: have you try reverting the \ to /?

Comment: As I said...the file exist, and no Errors in the path

Comment: @Luca91 - have you tried `os.listdir("C:\Users\L18938\Desktop\Vehicle_to_grid\analysis\")`

Comment: You have got an error in your path ... because windows file-path "C:\my\path" is not compatible with UNIX file-path ...

Answer (score 1):

Your Traceback let show you that the python interpreter is running in Unix file path mode (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py`)

*When you are under `Anaconda`, you are in pure windows and your traceback will be something like (`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py`)*

Anaconda will reach file with a Windows type file-path, and Zeppelin will reach file in a UNIX type file-path.

Your issue is definitely relative to **how you specify your path in Zeppelin**, you can't use Windows path, but you you may try something like that:

```
frequency=pd.read_csv("file:///C:/Users/L18938/Desktop/Vehicle_to_grid/analysis/Frequency_March_2018.csv", nrows=86401)
```